# How does one convert vbYes / vbNo to Boolean?

Tags: excel, vba

This code displays a MsgBox and asks a question. The result is returned in a VbMsgBoxResult and is converted to Boolean.

```
Dim gobox as VbMsgBoxResult
dim go as boolean

gobox = MsgBox("Question?", vbYesNo, "Descriptive Titel")
If gobox = vbYes Then
go = True
Else
go = False
End If
```

Is there an easier way to convert VbMsgBoxResult to Boolean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe just

```
go = (MsgBox("Question?", vbYesNo, "Descriptive Titel") = vbYes)
```

Comment: Yeah that works.. Still not sure if there is a way to really convert them into oneantoher without the comparison.. But definetly much shorter.

Comment: I do not think so. VbMsgBoxResult is an enumeration with seven values.

Comment: Ahh so that type covers also other msgbox types like YesNoCancel ect. got it. Thank you for the quick reply.

Comment: yes, just have a look in the object browser (press F2 in the VBE for that) and search for VbMsgBoxResult.

Comment: I _guess_  you could also use `go = MsgBox("Question?", vbYesNo, "Descriptive Titel") - 7` as `vbYes` = 6, `vbNo` = 7, `True` = -1 and `False` = 0 (I'll add that I wouldn't as the answer given is easier to read).